# Canvas.DrawCircle VS ShapeDrawable.setBounds()

Tags: android, drawable, shapes

What is a more efficient methods for drawing circles on a canvas.

I can do it two ways:

1. Use `canvas.drawcircle(...)`
2. `ShapeDrawable.SetBounds()` followed by `ShapeDrawable.draw(canvas)`

What renders faster? What's better practice? Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drawCircle() should be faster.